# Ceiling and Sorting

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on a chart which is within a 'List'. I am breaking the report with 10 rows each page (Ceiling). when I apply sort on my column, the sorting is done on every 10 rows but not on overall values in my column (Getting first 10 rows on first page and sorting, then next 10 rows on 2nd page and sorting....I want all the rows sorted first and then get into the report.)
I have ordered by the column in my query but it is not working.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Cris

Answer (score 0):

Check the sorting on your list as well as the sorting on your table - generally using a list involves two tablix, one inside the other. The inside tablix (usually just a table) get's its results from the outer tablix (the list). That means if you are sorting only at the inside level, the 10 results will be sorted but not the entire result set.

Other places to check include any groups you may be using in your tablix.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response. I will recheck my work again.